How to change exporting scale using Python?
When we export an .stl via File>Export>STL - we see a window which has a Scale variable.
This one:


• This variable is named WM_OT_stl_export.global_scale
How can I access this variable using Python ?

There is no direct Python access to the last_properties that are being stored after the operator has finished and then are reused on the next operator run. So it is either the default value or stored internally.
Workarounds
If the operator is running modally, the property can be accessed this way.
import bpy

# bpy.data.window_managers[0].windows[1].screen.areas[0].spaces[0].active_operator

for window in bpy.data.window_managers[0].windows:
    for aria in window.screen.areas:
        for space in aria.spaces:

            if not hasattr(space, 'active_operator'):
                continue
            
            if not space.active_operator:
                continue

            if bpy.types.EXPORT_MESH_OT_stl.bl_rna is space.active_operator.bl_rna:
                space.active_operator.properties.global_scale += 1
                aria.tag_redraw()


When you draw the operator's button the property can be assigned using OperatorProperties the return value.
import bpy

class TEST_PT_test_op(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PT_test_op'
    bl_label = 'Test'
    bl_category = 'TEST'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        
        op = self.layout.operator('export_mesh.stl')
        op.global_scale = 665

bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_test_op)

Or set the property as the function argument.
import bpy
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl('INVOKE_DEFAULT', global_scale = 123)

The property definition can be edited this way but you need to re-register the operator's class.
import bpy

op_class = bpy.types.EXPORT_MESH_OT_stl

op_class.__annotations__['global_scale'].keywords['default'] = 3
bpy.utils.unregister_class(op_class)
bpy.utils.register_class(op_class)


Hello, @unwave! :) – These workarounds are EXACTLY what I needed – you've helped me again – Many thanks ! ❤️

I am glad to help you.
